# forward slash key presses automatically

Tags: keyboard

The forward slash key is pressed automatically on my asus x540l laptop. Tried disabling the same but couldn't find a noob level guide to help me with it. My system is running kubuntu 20.04 lts release.

Comment: This is a question and answer site. Please edit your question and question title such that the question comes forward clearly.

Comment: apologies if the format of the question is not right , i am a noob stiil learning my way around linux.  if you do not understand the problem then i am willing to clarify.